# Galleria - pauseOnInteraction

Tags: galleria

I'm using Galleria 1.2.8 and everything is fine so far. [`pauseOnInteraction`](http://galleria.io/docs/options/pauseOnInteraction/) makes the animation stop on the next picture.

Is there a chance to stop the animation on the current picture by clicking on the current picture?